# How do I prevent users from viewing resources' entries that don't belong to them

Tags: node.js, rest, express

This is my first time writing a REST API and I am having some trouble designing my routes. So these are my resources: Students, Instructors, and Courses. I only want students and instructors to be able to view courses that they are enrolled in. I am using Node, Express, and MongoDB.

My question is where should this logic go according to best practices? I am only concerned with routes with a specific resource id such as courses/:id, if a user enters an id of a course that doesn't belong to them, I want to reject their request.

Comment: Generally permissions-related checks live in middleware.  And the bonus question is far too vague to give a helpful answer. SO can't help you make design decision about your app.

Comment: So should i just use middleware to check if a user is enrolled in the course, the student object has an array of course references? Is it acceptable to query the database from middleware?

Comment: Why not add the check to your existing db query?  You just want to limit what is returned from a select stmt, no?  Why can't this go into your where clause, and remove the need for additional code-level checks?  Without specific code, it's hard to offer specific advice

Comment: Ya I guess that would also work